# `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

I postes this question because I didn't find any related answer on stackoverflow. I did everything. I will explain what I have tried.
When I start the Rails server using `rails s`, I get the following output:

```
/Users/nour/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/nour/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/nour/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /Users/nour/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Output for `gem list`:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jar-dependencies (0.2.6)
jruby-openssl (0.9.19 java)
json (1.8.0 java)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.2)
```

Output for `gem install rails`:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)
    setting default path failed: Invalid keystore format
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Output for `bundle install`:

```
/Users/nour/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/nour/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/nour/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /Users/nour/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

Output for `gem install bundler`:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)
    setting default path failed: Invalid keystore format
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

$ gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

aasm (3.4.0)
actionmailer (4.2.6, 4.2.5, 4.2.4, 4.1.10, 4.1.8, 4.1.7, 4.1.6, 4.1.4, 4.1.0, 4.0.2, 3.2.13, 3.2.2, 2.3.18)
actionpack (4.2.6, 4.2.5, 4.2.4, 4.1.10, 4.1.8, 4.1.7, 4.1.6, 4.1.4, 4.1.0, 4.0.2, 3.2.13, 3.2.2, 2.3.18)
actionview (4.2.6, 4.2.5, 4.2.4, 4.1.10, 4.1.8, 4.1.7, 4.1.6, 4.1.4, 4.1.0)
active_model_serializers (0.8.3)
active_shipping (1.6.0, 1.4.3)
active_utils (3.2.0, 3.0.0, 2.2.3)
activejob (4.2.6, 4.2.5, 4.2.4)
activejob_backport (0.0.3)
activemerchant (1.53.0, 1.44.1, 1.43.3)
activemodel (4.2.6, 4.2.5, 4.2.4, 4.1.10, 4.1.8, 4.1.7, 4.1.6, 4.1.4, 4.1.0, 4.0.2, 3.2.13, 3.2.2)
activerecord (4.2.6, 4.2.5, 4.2.4, 4.1.10, 4.1.8, 4.1.7, 4.1.6, 4.1.4, 4.1.0, 4.0.2, 3.2.13, 3.2.2, 2.3.18)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activeresource (3.2.13, 3.2.2, 2.3.18)
activesupport (4.2.6, 4.2.5, 4.2.4, 4.1.10, 4.1.8, 4.1.7, 4.1.6, 4.1.4, 4.1.0, 4.0.2, 3.2.13, 3.2.2, 2.3.18)
acts-as-taggable-on (3.5.0)
acts_as_commentable (4.0.2)
acts_as_indexed (0.8.3)
acts_as_list (0.7.6, 0.7.4, 0.7.2, 0.3.0)
acts_as_votable (0.10.0)
addressable (2.5.2, 2.4.0, 2.3.8, 2.3.6)
ahoy_matey (1.4.2, 1.4.0, 1.2.1)
ancestry (2.1.0)
angularjs-rails (1.2.22)
animate-rails (1.0.10, 1.0.9, 1.0.8, 1.0.7)
anjlab-bootstrap-rails (3.0.0.3)
annotate (2.6.5)
arbre (1.0.3, 1.0.2)
arel (6.0.4, 6.0.3, 5.0.1.20140414130214, 4.0.2, 3.0.3)
asset_sync (1.1.0)
auto_html (1.6.4)
autoprefixer-rails (2.2.0.20140804)
awesome_nested_set (3.0.1)
awesome_print (1.8.0, 1.6.1, 1.2.0)
aws-sdk (2.1.30, 1.66.0, 1.27.0)
aws-sdk-core (2.1.30)
aws-sdk-resources (2.1.30)
aws-sdk-v1 (1.66.0)
aws_cf_signer (0.1.3)
axiom-types (0.1.1)
babosa (1.0.2)
bcrypt (3.1.11, 3.1.10, 3.1.9, 3.1.7)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
best_in_place (3.0.2)
better_errors (2.0.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
binding_of_caller (0.7.3, 0.7.2)
bootstrap-material-design (0.1.1)
bootstrap-sass (3.3.1.0, 3.2.0.2, 3.2.0.1, 2.3.1.3)
bootstrap_form (2.2.0)
bourbon (3.2.4, 3.2.3)
breadcrumbs_on_rails (2.3.1)
browser (2.2.0, 2.1.0, 1.0.1)
bson (2.3.0)
buftok (0.2.0)
builder (3.2.3, 3.2.2, 3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.16.0)
byebug (9.0.6, 9.0.5, 8.2.5, 8.2.4, 8.2.2, 8.2.1, 6.0.2, 5.0.0, 3.4.0)
callsite (0.0.11)
camertron-eprun (1.1.0)
cancan (1.6.10)
cancancan (1.9.2, 1.8.4)
canonical-rails (0.0.7)
capybara (2.4.4, 2.4.1)
capybara-screenshot (1.0.3)
caracal (1.0.4)
carmen (1.0.2, 1.0.1)
carrierwave (0.10.0)
celluloid (0.16.0)
CFPropertyList (2.3.1)
chartkick (2.0.0, 1.4.1)
choice (0.2.0, 0.1.6)
chunky_png (1.3.10, 1.3.8, 1.3.4, 1.3.3)
cldr-plurals-runtime-rb (1.0.0)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cloudinary (1.0.76)
cocaine (0.5.8, 0.5.7, 0.5.5, 0.5.4)
cocoon (1.2.6)
codeclimate-test-reporter (0.4.1)
coderay (1.1.0)
coercible (1.0.0)
coffee-rails (4.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.0.1, 3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.4.1, 2.3.0)
coffee-script-source (1.12.2, 1.10.0, 1.9.1.1, 1.9.1, 1.9.0, 1.8.0, 1.7.1)
colorator (0.1)
colored (1.2)
colorize (0.7.3)
columnize (0.9.0, 0.8.9)
commonjs (0.2.7)
compass (0.12.7, 0.12.2)
compass-rails (2.0.0, 1.1.7)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
connection_pool (2.0.0)
countries (1.1.0, 0.9.3)
country_select (2.1.1)
crass (1.0.3, 1.0.2)
css_parser (1.3.5)
css_splitter (0.4.2)
cssminify (1.0.2)
currencies (0.4.2)
daemons (1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.1.9, 1.0.10)
database_cleaner (1.3.0)
debug_inspector (0.0.3, 0.0.2)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.5)
decorators (2.0.1)
deface (1.0.1)
delayed_job (4.1.2, 4.1.1, 4.0.4, 4.0.2)
delayed_job_active_record (4.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.0.2)
delayed_job_web (1.2.9)
descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
devise (4.4.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.1, 3.5.6, 3.5.5, 3.5.2, 3.4.1, 3.4.0, 3.3.0)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
docile (1.1.5)
domain_name (0.5.25, 0.5.24)
dotenv (1.0.2)
dotenv-rails (1.0.2)
dragonfly (1.0.12)
draper (1.4.0)
dynamic_form (1.1.4)
easy_translate (0.5.0)
email_spec (1.6.0)
enumerable-lazy (0.0.1)
equalizer (0.0.11, 0.0.9)
errbase (0.0.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.2.0.1, 1.0.8, 1.0.7, 1.0.3)
exception_notification (4.2.1, 4.1.4, 4.1.2)
excon (0.45.4, 0.39.5)
execjs (2.7.0, 2.6.0, 2.5.2, 2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.2, 2.2.1)
factory_girl (4.5.0, 4.4.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.5.0, 4.4.1)
faker (1.4.3)
faraday (0.9.2, 0.9.0)
fedex (3.9.1)
ffaker (1.25.0)
ffi (1.9.25, 1.9.18, 1.9.10, 1.9.9, 1.9.8, 1.9.6, 1.9.3)
filters_spam (0.5)
fission (0.5.0)
fog (1.32.0, 1.23.0)
fog-atmos (0.1.0)
fog-aws (0.7.4)
fog-brightbox (0.8.0, 0.5.0)
fog-core (1.32.0, 1.24.0)
fog-ecloud (0.1.1)
fog-google (0.0.7)
fog-json (1.0.2, 1.0.0)
fog-local (0.2.1)
fog-powerdns (0.1.1)
fog-profitbricks (0.0.5)
fog-radosgw (0.0.4)
fog-riakcs (0.1.0)
fog-sakuracloud (1.0.1)
fog-serverlove (0.1.2)
fog-softlayer (0.4.7, 0.3.17)
fog-storm_on_demand (0.1.1)
fog-terremark (0.1.0)
fog-vmfusion (0.1.0)
fog-voxel (0.1.0)
fog-xml (0.1.2)
font-awesome-less (4.2.0)
font-awesome-rails (4.6.3.1, 4.6.3.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.2.0.0)
font-awesome-sass (4.4.0, 4.2.2, 4.2.1)
fontcustom (1.3.8)
formatador (0.2.5)
formtastic (3.1.3, 3.0.0, 2.3.1)
formtastic_i18n (0.4.1, 0.1.1)
foundation (1.0.4)
foundation-rails (5.4.5.0)
frank (1.0.12)
friendly_id (5.1.0, 5.0.4)
fssm (0.2.10)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
geocoder (1.3.7, 1.3.6, 1.2.12, 1.2.9, 1.2.7, 1.2.6, 1.2.5)
gibbon (2.2.4, 1.2.1)
globalid (0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.7, 0.3.6)
globalize (5.0.1)
gmaps4rails (2.1.2)
gon (5.2.3)
google_places (0.24.0)
grape (0.16.2)
groupdate (3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.5.0)
guard (2.8.2)
guard-rails (0.7.0)
guard-rspec (4.3.1)
haml (4.0.7, 4.0.6, 4.0.5, 3.2.0.rc.4, 3.1.8)
haml-rails (0.9.0, 0.5.3)
has_scope (0.6.0, 0.6.0.rc)
hashie (3.4.4, 3.3.1)
highline (1.6.21)
hike (1.2.3)
hirb (0.7.3, 0.7.2)
hitimes (1.2.3, 1.2.2)
html2haml (2.0.0)
htmlentities (4.3.2)
htmltoword (0.5.1)
http (0.6.2)
http-cookie (1.0.2)
http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
httparty (0.14.0, 0.13.7, 0.13.1)
i18n (0.9.5, 0.9.3, 0.9.1, 0.9.0, 0.8.6, 0.8.1, 0.7.0, 0.6.11, 0.6.1)
i18n-spec (0.6.0)
i18n-tasks (0.7.8)
i18n_data (0.7.0)
ice_nine (0.11.2, 0.11.0)
inflecto (0.0.2)
inherited_resources (1.6.0, 1.5.1, 1.4.1)
interactive_editor (0.0.11, 0.0.10)
io-console (0.4.2)
ipaddress (0.8.0)
iso (0.2.1)
jbuilder (2.7.0, 2.6.4, 2.6.3, 2.6.0, 2.5.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.16, 2.2.12, 2.2.10, 2.2.6, 2.2.5, 2.2.4, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.1.3, 1.5.3)
jekyll (3.1.6)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.4.0)
jekyll-watch (1.4.0)
jmespath (1.1.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.6)
jquery-rails (4.3.1, 4.2.1, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 3.1.5, 3.1.4, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1)
jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1, 5.0.5, 5.0.3, 5.0.2, 5.0.0, 4.2.1)
json (2.0.1, 1.8.6, 1.8.3, 1.8.2, 1.8.1)
jwt (1.0.0)
kaminari (0.17.0, 0.16.3, 0.16.1, 0.15.1)
kramdown (1.5.0)
launchy (2.4.3, 2.4.2)
less (2.4.0)
letter_opener (1.6.0, 1.4.1, 1.2.0)
libv8 (3.16.14.15, 3.16.14.13, 3.16.14.3 x86_64-darwin-13)
liquid (3.0.6)
listen (3.0.8, 2.10.1, 2.8.1, 2.7.11)
loofah (2.1.1, 2.1.0.rc2, 2.0.3)
lumberjack (1.0.9)
mail (2.7.0, 2.6.6, 2.6.4, 2.6.3, 2.6.1, 2.5.4, 2.4.4)
maildir (2.2.1)
memoizable (0.4.2)
mercenary (0.3.6)
meta_request (0.3.4)
metaclass (0.0.4)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1, 3.0, 2.99.1, 2.99, 2.6.2, 2.6.1, 2.5, 2.4.3, 2.3, 1.25.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521, 3.2016.0221)
mimemagic (0.3.0)
mini_magick (4.3.6, 3.8.1)
mini_mime (1.0.0)
mini_portile (0.6.2, 0.6.1, 0.6.0)
mini_portile2 (2.3.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.0)
minitest (5.11.3, 5.10.3, 5.10.1, 5.9.1, 5.9.0, 5.8.4, 5.8.3, 5.8.1, 5.8.0, 5.7.0, 5.6.1, 5.5.1, 5.4.3, 5.4.2, 5.4.1, 5.4.0, 4.7.5)
minitest-rails (2.2.1)
mocha (1.1.0)
modernizr-rails (2.7.1)
monetize (0.4.1)
money (6.2.1)
mongrel (1.2.0.pre2)
moped (2.0.0)
multi_json (1.13.1, 1.12.2, 1.12.1, 1.11.3, 1.11.2, 1.11.1, 1.11.0, 1.10.1)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
mustermann19 (0.4.4)
mysql2 (0.4.4)
naught (1.0.0)
neat (1.5.1)
negative_captcha (0.4)
nested_form (0.3.2)
net-http-persistent (2.9.4)
net-scp (1.2.1)
net-ssh (2.9.4, 2.9.2, 2.9.1)
netrc (0.10.3, 0.10.2, 0.9.0, 0.8.0, 0.7.7)
nokogiri (1.8.2, 1.8.1, 1.7.1, 1.6.8.1, 1.6.8, 1.6.7.2, 1.6.7.1, 1.6.7, 1.6.6.2, 1.6.4.1, 1.6.3.1)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (1.0.0)
offsite_payments (2.0.1)
omniauth (1.2.2)
omniauth-facebook (2.0.0)
omniauth-github (1.1.2)
omniauth-linkedin (0.2.0)
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.2.0)
omniauth-twitter (1.0.1)
optionable (0.2.0)
origin (2.1.1)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
pandoc-ruby (2.0.0)
paperclip (4.3.7, 4.3.6, 4.3.3, 4.3.2, 4.3.1, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 3.5.4)
paranoia (2.0.2)
paypal-recurring (1.1.0)
pdf-core (0.6.1, 0.2.5)
pg (1.0.0, 0.21.0, 0.20.0, 0.19.0, 0.18.4, 0.18.3, 0.18.2, 0.18.1, 0.17.1, 0.15.1, 0.15.0)
pkg-config (1.1.7)
polyamorous (1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.0)
polyglot (0.3.5)
pony (1.11)
prawn (2.1.0, 1.2.1)
prawn-table (0.1.2)
premailer (1.8.2)
premailer-rails (1.8.0)
pry (0.10.3, 0.10.1)
pry-rails (0.3.4, 0.3.2)
psych (2.0.5)
public_suffix (3.0.2)
quantified (1.0.1)
quiet_assets (1.0.3)
rabl (0.9.4.pre1)
rack (1.6.8, 1.6.5, 1.6.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.4, 1.5.3, 1.5.2, 1.4.5, 1.1.6)
rack-accept (0.4.5)
rack-attack (4.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-contrib (1.2.0)
rack-cors (0.2.9)
rack-pjax (1.0.0, 0.8.0)
rack-protection (1.5.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.4)
rack-test (0.6.3, 0.6.2)
radriar (0.1.0.alpha.3)
rails (4.2.6, 4.2.5, 4.2.4, 4.1.10, 4.1.8, 4.1.7, 4.1.6, 4.1.4, 4.1.0, 3.2.13, 3.2.2)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.9, 1.0.8, 1.0.7)
rails-erd (1.4.4, 1.1.0)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3, 1.0.2)
rails-i18n (4.0.3)
rails-simple-search (0.9.8)
rails_12factor (0.0.3, 0.0.2)
rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5, 0.0.4, 0.0.2)
rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5, 0.0.4, 0.0.3)
railties (4.2.6, 4.2.5, 4.2.4, 4.1.10, 4.1.8, 4.1.7, 4.1.6, 4.1.4, 4.1.0, 4.0.2, 3.2.13, 3.2.2)
rake (12.3.1, 12.3.0, 12.1.0, 12.0.0, 11.3.0, 11.2.2, 11.1.2, 11.1.1, 10.5.0, 10.4.2, 10.4.0, 10.3.2, 10.1.0)
ransack (1.6.6, 1.5.1, 1.4.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.3)
rapidfire (2.1.0)
rb-fsevent (0.10.2, 0.9.7, 0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.10, 0.9.7, 0.9.5)
rb-readline (0.5.1)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
rdoc (4.3.0, 4.2.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.2, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 3.12.2)
recaptcha (4.8.0, 3.3.0, 3.0.0, 1.0.2, 0.4.0)
redcarpet (3.3.4, 3.3.3, 3.1.2)
ref (2.0.0, 1.0.5)
referer-parser (0.3.0)
refinerycms (3.0.0, 0.9.7.15)
refinerycms-core (3.0.0)
refinerycms-i18n (3.0.1)
refinerycms-images (3.0.0)
refinerycms-pages (3.0.0)
refinerycms-resources (3.0.0)
remotipart (1.2.1)
representable (2.3.0)
request_store (1.3.1, 1.2.1, 1.1.0)
rerun (0.10.0)
responders (2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.0.0)
rest-client (1.8.0, 1.7.2, 1.6.9)
rinku (1.5.1)
roar (1.0.4)
rouge (1.11.0)
routing-filter (0.5.1)
rspec (3.1.0)
rspec-core (3.1.7, 3.1.0, 3.0.4)
rspec-expectations (3.1.2, 3.1.0, 3.0.4)
rspec-mocks (3.1.3, 3.1.0, 3.0.4)
rspec-rails (3.1.0, 3.0.2)
rspec-support (3.1.2, 3.1.0, 3.0.4)
ruby-graphviz (1.2.2, 1.0.9)
ruby_parser (3.7.2)
rubyzip (1.2.0)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
safe_yaml (1.0.4)
safely_block (0.1.1)
sass (3.5.5, 3.5.3, 3.5.2, 3.4.23, 3.4.22, 3.4.21, 3.4.20, 3.4.9, 3.2.19, 3.2.0)
sass-listen (4.0.0)
sass-rails (5.0.7, 5.0.6, 5.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.4, 4.0.3, 3.2.6)
sdoc (0.4.2, 0.4.1)
select2-rails (3.5.9.1)
seo_meta (2.0.0.rc.1)
sequel (3.20.0)
sexp_processor (4.6.0)
simple_form (3.0.2)
simple_oauth (0.2.0)
simplecov (0.9.1, 0.9.0)
simplecov-html (0.8.0)
sinatra (1.4.5, 1.0)
sitemap_generator (5.1.0)
slim (2.1.0, 2.0.3)
slim-rails (2.1.5)
slop (3.6.0)
snooby (0.1.5)
sort_alphabetical (1.0.1)
speakingurl-rails (1.1.5)
spina (0.7.0)
spina-template (0.3.0)
spoon (0.0.6, 0.0.4)
spree (2.4.1)
spree_api (2.4.1)
spree_backend (2.4.1)
spree_cmd (2.4.1)
spree_core (2.4.1, 2.3.2)
spree_frontend (2.4.1)
spree_sample (2.4.1)
spring (2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.7.2, 1.7.1, 1.6.4, 1.6.3, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.6.0, 1.4.0, 1.3.6, 1.3.3, 1.3.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.3)
sprockets (3.7.1, 3.7.0, 3.6.0, 3.5.2, 2.12.4, 2.12.3, 2.12.1, 2.11.3, 2.11.0, 2.2.3, 2.1.4)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.0.4, 3.0.3, 3.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.2.4, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.1.4, 2.1.3)
sprockets_better_errors (0.0.4)
sqlite3 (1.3.13, 1.3.12, 1.3.11, 1.3.10, 1.3.9, 1.3.7, 1.3.6, 1.3.5)
state_machine (1.2.0)
stringex (1.5.1)
stripe (1.30.2, 1.15.0)
subexec (0.2.3)
sweet-alert (0.0.5)
sweet-alert-confirm (0.0.3)
taps (0.3.24)
temple (0.6.10, 0.6.9, 0.6.8)
term-ansicolor (1.3.0)
terminal-table (1.4.5)
test-unit (2.1.2.0)
therubyracer (0.12.2, 0.12.1)
thin (1.7.0, 1.6.4, 1.6.3, 1.6.2)
thor (0.20.0, 0.19.4, 0.19.1, 0.14.6)
thread (0.1.4)
thread_safe (0.3.6, 0.3.5, 0.3.4)
tilt (2.0.8, 2.0.7, 2.0.5, 2.0.2, 1.4.1)
timers (4.0.4, 4.0.1)
tins (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.15)
truncate_html (0.9.2)
ttfunk (1.4.0, 1.2.2)
turbo-sprockets-rails3 (0.2.9)
turbolinks (5.1.1, 5.1.0, 5.0.1, 2.5.3, 2.5.2, 2.5.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.2)
turbolinks-source (5.1.0, 5.0.3, 5.0.0)
twitter (5.11.0)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8)
twitter_cldr (3.1.0)
twocheckout (0.3.1)
tzinfo (1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 0.3.42, 0.3.41)
uber (0.0.15)
uglifier (4.1.11, 4.1.5, 3.2.0, 3.0.3, 3.0.2, 3.0.0, 2.7.2, 2.7.1, 2.7.0, 2.5.3)
underscore-rails (1.7.0)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.1)
unicode_utils (1.4.0)
user_agent_parser (2.3.0)
uuidtools (2.1.5)
valid_email (0.0.10)
validates_zipcode (0.0.8)
versioncake (2.3.1)
virtus (1.0.5, 1.0.3)
w3c_validators (1.2)
warden (1.2.7, 1.2.6, 1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.3)
web-console (2.3.0, 2.2.1)
will_paginate (3.0.7)
will_paginate-bootstrap (1.0.1)
xpath (2.0.0)
zilch-authorisation (0.0.1)
zurb-foundation (4.3.2)
```

ruby -v

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

$ rbenv set global 2.1.2

```
rbenv: no such command `set'
```

What do you think could be the problem? Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is updating my OS X certs with brew (https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1736) :

```
brew update
brew install openssl
brew tap raggi/ale
brew install openssl-osx-ca
```

Then updating my ruby version by `rbenv install 2.4.0`

```
rbenv local 2.4.0

gem install bundler
gem update --system
```

And it work :)

Comment: Appreciate if anyone can paste linux commands/guides for same steps mentioned above.
OS : "Alpine Linux v3.12"

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem seems to be bundler. What operating system and Ruby version are you using? It may be a problem with old OpenSSL library, so you can not install bundler and everything after it.

If you are using jRuby (your `gem list` output tells so), your problem seems to be the same as described in [link](https://gist.github.com/kendagriff/adec3713b4dfe6a1abdf). And there is a solution as well.

Maybe you forgot to set `2.1.2` version of ruby as global? (`rbenv set global 2.1.2`)

Comment: my mistake: `rbenv global 2.1.2` is the right command. Your `gem list` says that you use jruby in your project. What IDE are you using?. Is there a `ruby-version` file in project? It may be hidden.

Comment: You mean this? $ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

Comment: no, in your project's root folder there can be hidden file `.ruby-version`. The version from this file overrides the system version of ruby.

Comment: Don't know how to know! please help

Comment: open the directory of your project in terminal and print `cat .ruby-version`

Comment: $ cat .ruby-version
cat: .ruby-version: No such file or directory

Comment: $ rbenv version
2.1.2 (set by /Users/nour/.rbenv/version)

Comment: :/  Maybe something wrong with your rbenv installation. Please uninstall it https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/148 and then install again https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-18-04. UPD oh, you use Mac, so something like https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Comment: $ rails s
/Users/nour/limo_rent_vancouver/bin/spring:10:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/nour/limo_rent_vancouver/Gemfile.lock (Errno::ENOENT)
 from /Users/nour/limo_rent_vancouver/bin/spring:10:in `read'
 from /Users/nour/limo_rent_vancouver/bin/spring:10:in `<top (required)>'
 from bin/rails:3:in `load'
 from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Comment: I solve it :) Thank you for your time and effort so appreciate it :) I post the answer